# confusion on c# string literals

Tags: c#, literals

I'm writing a program where I am referring to a variable that contains a path to a file. When I assign the variable like this:

```
string strFile = @"\\server\share\restOfPath\file.txt";
```

I would think it would come out like it is shown because of the "@" at the beginning of the variable. Instead, this is how it comes out when I display it to the console:

```
\\\\server\\share\\restOfPath\\file.txt
```

I started researching and found this page from MSDN that supports my thinking that it should come out as I put it in, yet it still comes out with the back slashes doubled.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx
Would someone please help me out to understand why this is happening

Comment: Your console is appending the escaping slashes. The *actual* value stored in memory is as you expect.

Comment: Not reproducible: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YMbDbL

Comment: @Rob why would it?

Comment: How are you "displaying it to the console?" If you're looking _in the debugger_ you will see the escape characters so you know they're slashes and not control codes.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string strFile = @"\\server\share\restOfPath\file.txt";
            Console.WriteLine(strFile);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the output \server\share\restOfPath\file.txt